# How to write simple popup message in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I write a simple popup message in ruby"

```
   if result == nil
  {

  }
```

If the above condition is satisfied, I want to display a simple message like "hello welcome".

Comment: what do you mean pop message? A browser alert?

Comment: yes. A simple browser alert.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using erb

```
<% if result == nil %>
  <%= javascript_tag "alert('hello welcome')" %>
<% end %>
```

Or even simpler:

```
<%= javascript_tag "alert('hello welcome')" unless result %>
```